# Json.NET Out of Memory Deserialization

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net

Here's my code. I'm getting an out of memory exception trying to deserialize. I've tried following other answers and can't get it to work. Any recommendations? The file is 121 MB.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
  using (JsonReader jr = new JsonTextReader(reader))
  {
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    data = serializer.Deserialize<MyObject>(jr);
  }
}
```

I've also tried this

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    using (JsonReader jr = new JsonTextReader(reader))
    {
        while (jr.Read())
        {
            if (jr.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
            {
                data = serializer.Deserialize<MyObject>(jr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`MyObject` is a `List<SubObject>`. `SubObject` contains four properties, one being `Data`. `Data` is a large string and where the majority of this large data is stored and likely where it's failing. There are only two or three `SubObjects` in the list

Comment: Needs to see a [mcve], specifically `MyObject` and the JSON in question.  Recommendations differ depending on whether you have a large number of tokens, a single very large string value.  For instance if you have a single huge Base64 string see maybe [Json.Net deserialize out of memory issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33480477/3744182).

Comment: Apologies for that, I edited it. That does sound like my problem, though it's not encoded. I'll keep looking into that issue specifically.

Comment: And be sure you're actually running in 64bit not 32.  See [What is the purpose of the “Prefer 32-bit” setting in Visual Studio and how does it actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12066861/3744182) and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/ide/how-to-configure-projects-to-target-platforms?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Json.NET always fully materializes every string property.  If you have switched to 64 bit and are still running out of memory materializing single properties you may need to switch to a different serializer.  E.g. `JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader` supports `ReadValueChunk()`, see [Parse huge OData JSON by streaming certain sections of the json to avoid LOH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56038495/3744182).

Comment: *MyObject is a `List<SubObject>`* - Can you share a small JSON sample with comments showing where the large quantities of data are -- i.e. a [mcve]?